# notifyiconwpf and GUI automation

Tags: automated-tests, caliburn.micro, pywinauto

I have an application that uses this application type that I need to automate. Unfortunately, the application window is invisible to my automation tools. Are there any suggested ways of working around this problem? I'm using pywinuto for automation. I can't even inspect the window data for this application.

EDIT:

```
from pywinauto import Application
from pywinauto import taskbar

app = Application().start("path/to/my/app")
#make the window visible
taskbar.ClickHiddenSystemTrayIcon("My App") 
#When I query the number of windows the app has.
len(app.Windows())
#I get zero windows. There should be at least one window
#because the window is currently visible.
```

I've also tried the findwindow methods for which I can get a WindowSpecification but it is not connected to any window.

Comment: Can you run the application from inside a cmd prompt?

Comment: @jmoon I can. It just starts the app though.

Comment: Which backend from pywinauto do you use? If you create `Application()` without params, it uses "win32" by default which is wrong for WPF app. Use `Application(backend="uia")` instead.

Comment: I've tried with both win32 and uia.

Comment: Need more details how you're trying to obtain window elements and what's expected?

Comment: @VasilyRyabov Added some additional details to the question.

Comment: @VasilyRyabov Nice job on pywinauto, by the way. It's far better than AutoIt .

Comment: Thanks! You're always welcome for more detailed feedback. We're constantly looking for improvement ideas. Also you can mark your own answer as accepted to indicate for others it's resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for this app to be automatable, the developer had to wrap the NotifyIconWPF in a standard window, conditionally, depending on command line switches. Once this was done, the windows for this application became accessible to pywinauto. It looks to me like Caliburn Micro, intentionally, disabled accessibility for this window class.